# Loading Module from services Folder rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to load a module from my service folder but i keep getting
 `uninitialized constant Api::V1::StoresController::Services`

```
my folder structure is app/services/store/find.rb

# find.rb
module Store
  module Find
    def self.call(params)
      store_id = params[:store_id]
      return Store.all if store_id.blank?
      return Store.find(store_id) if store_id.present?
    end
  end
end
```

and my controller is in app/controllers/api/v1/stores_controller.rb

```
class Api::V1::StoresController < Api::BaseController
    def index
        @stores = Services::Store::Find.call(params)
        respond_with(@stores, :status => :ok)
    end
end
```

i've tried alot of solutions like config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/services" but still can't use my service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constant you want is named `Store::Find`; `Services` is not part of the namespace.

```
    @stores = Store::Find.call(params)
```

Comment: how can i use it as Services::Store ? because i have a model called Store ? i'm following tutorials here https://medium.freecodecamp.org/ruby-on-rails-how-to-extract-code-to-service-objects-1c73148cc715